# Is it possible to reference a variable from my codebehind in an external .js file?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I'm cleaning up some old projects and moving the javascript from my .aspx pages to an external javascript file.

In a few of my pages, I reference variables from the C# side in my javascript. For example:

```
var myVal = <%= idNumber %>;
```

where `idNumber` is a public variable set in my codebehind.

This no longer works when I move the script to an external file, which makes sense. I thought explicitly stating `window.idNumber` might work, but I was incorrect.

Is there a way to make this work? If not, what is the best practice? Should I keep the js similar to this example in the page itself and call "external" methods? Can I assign a .js file to a specific page and only that page (just to keep my code clean)?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem a while back as well. My solution was to re-factor my JS code to use function parameters and then have my code-behind call the functions. This has the added benefit that it makes your JS code more re-usable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now my OCD is going to force me to treat my .js like classes and separate all of my functions based on something other than the page it is used for. You wouldn't happen to have a link to an article or other thread about this would you? It's been a while since I tried calling my js from the code-behind and I remember it being tricky/messy

Comment: @MrCarder I will try to find you some examples. I don't remember it being tricky though...

Comment: @MrCarder [This article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/314_Multiple_Ways_to_Call_Javascript_Function_from_CodeBehind_in_ASPNet.aspx) seems to be the most thorough, but I didn't look at many. If you have any more problems along the way, feel free to open a new question (if it hasn't already been asked) and I am sure you will get some help! Good luck!